# CSS is not getting applied in function call of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my dashboard all the css and js are getting applied, but when i call a function from other controller then the css and js will not get applied.
My code from view is - File sidebar.php:

```
<li><a href="farm/add_farm"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Add Farm</a></li>
```

And controller is - farm.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Farm extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('farm_info');
}



public function add_farm()
    {
        $this->load->view('farm/add_farm');
    }
}
```

Also my .htaccess file contain

```
# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please help me with this, i will provide you any other info if you want

Comment: How are you referencing the path to the .css and the .js files. It could be that when you use site_url or just the relative path that it gets interpreted from the current URL plus the path(incorrect) to the files. Ie. you current path is example.com - from here your css will get referenced correctly eg example.com/css/style.css but when your on example.com/dashboard depending on whether you use site_url or base_url you'd get example.com/dashboard/css/style.css (this will result in a 404 error)

Comment: I solved my problem, But thanks for replying. Thank you very much.

Comment: What was your problem?